# Facing issue in EJB while using two datasources ( DB2 & Oracle )

Tags: java, ejb

Kindly help us on resolving the below two issues.

1.) Exception while saving data to two different databases (Db2 and oracle) - (EJB Module)

```
WTRN0078E: An attempt by the transaction manager to call start on a transactional resource has resulted in an error. The error code was XAER_PROTO. The exception stack trace follows: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1034)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:251)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.CMXAResourceImpl.start(CMXAResourceImpl.java:219)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAResourceBase.start(JTAResourceBase.java:145)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RegisteredResources.startRes(RegisteredResources.java:1241)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:649)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:3296)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerSet.enlist(TranManagerSet.java:407)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerSet.enlist(TranManagerSet.java:365)
        at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.TranManagerSet.enlist(TranManagerSet.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.pool.ConnectO.enlist(ConnectO.java:1171)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.pool.ConnectO.enlist(ConnectO.java:775)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.pool.ConnectO.preInvoke(ConnectO.java:2242)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.proxy.Proxy.__preInvoke(Proxy.java:269)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.proxy.Proxy.__preInvoke(Proxy.java:249)
        at com.ibm.ejs.cm.proxy.OracleConnectionProxy.prepareStatement(OracleConnectionProxy.java:188)
        at com.marks.ims.integration.jde.dao.AddressBookDAO.copyAddressBookZRecord(AddressBookDAO.java:305)
        at com.marks.ims.integration.jde.dao.AddressBookDAO.update(AddressBookDAO.java:92)
        at com.marks.ims.integration.jde.JDEInterfaceGateway.updateAccount(JDEInterfaceGateway.java:88)
        at com.marks.bizacct.model.ejb.BusinessAccountServicesBean.doInterfaceProcessing(BusinessAccountServicesBean.java:318)

CONM6016E: The system is unable to enlist with the transaction.  Issuing new (TransactionAbortedException).
```

2.) Sometimes getting exception in loading data from two different databases (Db2 and oracle) - (EJB Module)

```
com.marks.bizacct.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Error attempting to find business account in findByKey()::BusinessAccountServicesBean - javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException: CORBA TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK 0x0 No; nested exception is:   org.omg.CORBA.TRANSACTION_ROLLEDBACK: javax.transaction.TransactionRolledbackException:  ; nested exception is: 
        com.ibm.websphere.csi.CSITransactionRolledbackException: Transaction marked rollbackonly  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
```

Comment: Are you using the same transaction for both commits? Or are you using distinct transactions? And how is their execution scheduled?

Comment: yes, using same transaction for both Db
tx.begin();
udpate();
tx.commit();

update(){
Dao.update();
Dao.insert();
}